# Need to create separate log file for jar file?

Tags: java, log4j, logging

I am creating a jar file that i need to provide to client, but my client is asking for separate logger for the jar file as this is doing some integration work.

anyone can suggest how can i create logger for only one jar file, can i put log4j.properties in same jar file.

I am using web-logic server. we will not deploy this jar file instead we will just keep it in domain lib folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the properties file is in the jar, then you could do something like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

The above assumes that the log4j.properties is in the root folder of the jar file.

If this does not work for your needs in this case then you can always use:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_for_some_jar.properties
```

If the other application is using Log4j as well. The easier method would be to just config your log4j file to send anything from your classes in your jar to a new log file like so:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, logfile

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.datePattern='-'dd'.log'
log4j.appender.logfile.File=log/radius-prod.log
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6r %d{ISO8601} %-5p %40.40c %x - %m\n

log4j.logger.foo.bar.Baz=DEBUG, myappender
log4j.additivity.foo.bar.Baz=false

log4j.appender.myappender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender.datePattern='-'dd'.log'
log4j.appender.myappender.File=log/access-ext-dmz-prod.log
log4j.appender.myappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6r %d{ISO8601} %-5p %40.40c %x - %m\n
```

Comment: Hi thanks, if we are creating static function for this, then "getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties")" line wont work, can we do any other thing for this.

Comment: You can just use the class name, not always ideal but you can do `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties")`. If you cant for what ever reason then you need to look at using reflection or stack traces - i.e. getStackTrace - `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.props")` You will have to experiment to determine which exact index you want.